# 'The type of navigation 'Site.operatives' is 'User[]' which is an array type. Collection navigation properties cannot be arrays.'

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, .net-5

I have never faced this problem before. I recently switched from azure sql server to local Db for testing.

I have been running the same thing for more than 3 months and I have never came across this issue.

I tried debugging and doing some research online, but no luck as I am still a noob XD

This happens on the service I have which is used to get siteById

```
public Site getSiteById(string id)
{
  var site = _appDbContext.Sites
    .FromSqlInterpolated($"SELECT * FROM [API].[dash_GetSiteStatus]({_userId}, {id})")
    .OrderBy(s => s.id)
    .FirstOrDefault();

  return site;
}
```

and the Site model looks like

```
public class Site 
 {

  public User[] operatives { get; set; }

 }
```

and my DBContext looks like

```
  public class AppDbContext : DbContext
 {
      public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
      {
      }

      public DbSet<Site> Sites { get; set; }
      .
      .
      public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
  }
```

[here is the snapshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fbjB.png)

Dependencies

```
<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Core" Version="1.17.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.9.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Files.Shares" Version="12.7.0" />
<PackageReference Include="EntityFramework.CodeFirstStoreFunctions" Version="1.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="GraphQL.Server.Ui.Voyager" Version="5.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="HotChocolate.AspNetCore" Version="11.2.2" />
<PackageReference Include="HotChocolate.AspNetCore.Authorization" Version="11.2.2" />
<PackageReference Include="HotChocolate.Data.Entityframework" Version="11.2.2" />
<PackageReference Include="JWT" Version="8.2.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="5.0.6" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob" Version="11.2.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityframeworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.6">
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityframeworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.6" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="5.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: AFAIK array types have never been supported. Are you sure you always used `User[]` instead of `ICollection<User>`? (BTW I removed the graphql tag, it's not related to the issue).

Comment: Yes, i am sure I was using User[ ]  for more than 3 or 4 months and had no problem.

Comment: I have added my csproj file with all dependencies

Comment: Well, you must have changed *something* other than localdb. Array is definitely not supported in ef-core 5.